# android studio doesn't work studio-bundle-141.1890965

Tags: java, android

I install android studio and then it shows this error and closed I install JDK and SDK before and can program with eclipse but now I want use android studio please help me? Why this error happen

[image: first page error]

and version is android-studio-bundle-141.1890965

Comment: Try to reinstall. Try the latest version also.

Comment: how can i report it?